# web services - HTTP GET request and response

Tags: c#

I have to write code to access a webservice - HTTP GET request and response.

Please let me know how to do this.  Any code samples will be helpful. I am clue less how to implement  this.

The following is a sample HTTP GET request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
GET /xmlWS/service.asmx/XmlResponse?StoreID=string&CustomerID=string&XMLMsg=string HTTP/1.1
Host: qa.testservice.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://aspnet.testservice.com/xmlws/service.asmx">string</string>
```

Comment: It's better to search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can use use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) with the URL in the request...

Answer (score 0):

XML Web Services, also known as ASMX services, were the predecessor of Windows Communication Foundation (WCF). You can access Web services by adding a service reference just as you would for any other WCF service. Any references added in this manner will target the latest version of the .NET Framework.

To add a Web reference to a project check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

or you can use HttpClient which as post and get methods

Answer (score -1):

You could use [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw.aspx). You need to encode url parameters, for example by using [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx).